# Day for sectionIdentifier for Custom Section Titles

Tags: objective-c, tableview

On Apple developer docs, there is Custom Section Titles (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/DateSectionTitles/Introduction/Intro.html) where it obtains the year and month.

I would like to grab the day so I can build a section title that has the day, month and year.

How would I grab the day from this code?

code:

```
/*
     Section information derives from an event's sectionIdentifier, which is a string representing the number (year * 1000) + month.
     To display the section title, convert the year and month components to a string representation.
     */

static NSDateFormatter *formatter = nil;

if (!formatter)
{
    formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setCalendar:[NSCalendar currentCalendar]];

    NSString *formatTemplate = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:@"MMMM YYYY" options:0 locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
    [formatter setDateFormat:formatTemplate];
}

NSInteger numericSection = [[theSection name] integerValue];
NSInteger year = numericSection / 1000;
NSInteger month = numericSection - (year * 1000);

NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
dateComponents.year = year;
dateComponents.month = month;
NSDate *date = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:dateComponents];

NSString *titleString = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
```

From the

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here in the above posted code It is a section info that you are getting.

And section means name of the Month and Year only, because you are ***fetching here only Month and Year, you are not fetching the date so, you will not have Day.***

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil)
    {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    /*
     Set up the fetched results controller.
     */
    // Create the fetch request for the entity.
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"APLEvent" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    // Sort using the timeStamp property.
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"timeStamp" ascending:YES];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor ]];

    // Use the sectionIdentifier property to group into sections.
    _fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"sectionIdentifier" cacheName:@"Root"];
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

Yew but through "APIEvent" and time stamp you can have day components..